# Should this behavior be modeled as an entity or domain service?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model, aggregate

Imagine that you're modeling SE (or SO) on DDD.

You decided to implement the "board" as an aggregate root. So the board has the method `AddNewQuestion(string question)`.

There are business rules that dictate that a given set of partners (think companies that advertise jobs) should be notified about question tagged with tags they chose to follow.

What is the cleanest approach here?

Should the creation of a new question be posted as an domain event to a queue or something that a latter notification service would pick up and deliver? Should I model the posting on a domain service so it can coordinate between the board, notification services and etc? Should I make this (notification of 3rd parties) a responsibility of the Board entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should the creation of a new question be posted as an domain event to a queue or something that a latter notification service would pick up and deliver? Should I model the posting on a domain service so it can coordinate between the board, notification services and etc? Should I make this (notification of 3rd parties) a responsibility of the Board entity?

Domain event is almost certainly the right starting point.

The plumbing between the surfacing of the domain event and the consumers might be push or pull based.

You've probably got at least one more piece of business model to work through - events for any given topic need to be run past a point in the model that is aware of the state of the current bids for that topic, to know which business get notified of the event.

> Should I model the posting on a domain service so it can coordinate between the board, notification services and etc?

Domain service is the wrong idea for an orchestration problem; the pattern you want to be thinking about here is "process manager".

> Should I make this (notification of 3rd parties) a responsibility of the Board entity?

No - separation of concerns.